# Using ISERDESE2 for maximum data rate of 640Mbps

Tags: fpga, frequency

I want to deserialize data out of a LM98640 which data rate is configurable from 40 Mbps to 640 Mbps, i will use an FPGA of series 7.
But looking at the datasheets i don't know which frequency parameter to look for to choose the right FPGA.
Frequency of BUFG? or the PLL? MMCM?

Comment: I will use the ISERDESE2 components to achieve the deserialization

Comment: Quite related to [this earlier question posted by the OP](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/358740/deserializing-high-speed-data)

Comment: You have already been told that every available Xilinx speed grade can handle these rates, so there's nothing to choose on that basis. You need to study the documentation in order to better understand how the clock resources are used with ISERDES2 -- you're going to have to do this anyway in order to complete the design -- and in the process, you'll answer your own question.

Comment: Unless i'm mistaking i don't see where i was told that every available xilinx speed grade can handle these rates and even so i'm a trying to understand why they can handle these rates. I have been reading these documents https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug472_7Series_Clocking.pdf and https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug471_7Series_SelectIO.pdf as well as the FPGAs Data Sheet:DC and AC Switching Characteristics for the different FPGA's and i'm trying understand them by asking questions. What i understood is..

Comment: What i understood is that depending on the clocking methods of the ISERDESE2 CLK (The high-speed clock input (CLK) to clock in the input serial data stream) can either be driven by a BUFIO or a BUFR or a PLL or a MCMM or a BUFG. 
So since my CLK is at 320MHz i should check in the datasheets that FmaxBUFIO, FmaxBUFR, FmaxPLL FmaxMCMM , or FmaxBUFG is superior to 320 MHz? I'm sorry if this seems repetitive, i'm just doing my best a trying to understand